# XPages Managed Bean ClassNotFoundException

Tags: xpages, managed-bean

I am trying to get a managed bean to work, when I preview the test page, I get an an error that it cannot instantiate the class and indicates a ClassNotFound exception.

The java classes are there and correct
The beans are in the faces-config file correctly.
I'm running designer 8.5.3.

What would be possible causes as to why the classes are not being found?

Thank you

Comment: Do you reference the correct Java package and class name in faces-config (with proper lowercase and uppercase)? Do you reference the correct bean name as stated in faces-config in your test XPage? Please show us parts of the bean, faces-config and the test XPage.

Comment: Try to 'clean' your project once more (Project -> Clean). It might be necessary to first make a small change (e.g. adding a space) to the class first. Your problem might also be related to this: http://dontpanic82.blogspot.nl/2011/12/classnotfoundexception-with-new-java.html : 8.5.3 has some issues with the new Code/Java element. I think they are fixed in one of the fixpacks (and 9).

Comment: Thank you Henrick and Mark for replying.  I will trying cleaning the project again. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As Per says, you need to provide some code examples so we can see if something is missing.

Also check out his blog post, http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2012/02/creating-your-first-managed-bean-for-xpages.html This is a great place to start and covers all the basics.

Simple thing like needing to implement 'Serializable' is commonly missed!

Comment: Thank you GForrest...will do.